# android - ionic build enoent error

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework

The following action results in error

```
D:\mobileapp\myApp>ionic build android
```

Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"

```
D:\mobileapp\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js 
D:\mobileapp\myApp
```

add to body class: platform-android

with

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\suffian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_111
```

Causes error:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Comment: please help some one what can i do ?